# Angular 2 webdriver not defined

Tags: angular

```
angular2-polyfills.js:332 Error: ReferenceError: webdriver is not defined(…)ZoneDelegate.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:332Zone.run @ angular2-polyfills.js:227(anonymous function) @ angular2-polyfills.js:576ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:365Zone.runTask @ angular2-polyfills.js:263drainMicroTaskQueue @ angular2-polyfills.js:482ZoneTask.invoke @ angular2-polyfills.js:434
```

> I get this error when starting angular 2 app and I don't understand
>   why. This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.11"
  }
}
```

> Does something happend with the beta 14 version or is a dependency
>   problem witch is not resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a wrong import from Webdriver